# How to draw blocks in Tetris with less code?

Tags: c++, tetris

Is there a way to do the print "0" part with less code? I tried various things, but I just crazy random prints. If I try a for loop with a variable that lets the BlockX array move up every time it prints a "0" it just flips out. even if I cap that variable at 3.

TIA

Edit: BlockX and BlockY are coordinates of blocks. Coordinates are defined somewhere else.

```
void Draw()
{

system("cls");
for (int i = 0; i < height + 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width + 1; j++)
    {
        if (j == 10)
        {
            cout << "|";
        }
        if (j == width)
        {
            cout << "|";
        }
        else if ((j == BlockX[0] && i == BlockY[0]) || (j == BlockX[1] && i == BlockY[1]) || (j == BlockX[2] && i == BlockY[2]) || (j == BlockX[3] && i == BlockY[3]))
        {
            cout << "0";                            
        }
        else
        {       
            cout << " ";
        }               
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: What are `BlockX` and `BlockY`?

Comment: They are coordinates of blocks that need to be printed. They are defined somewhere else. It is always an array of 4 items with different coordinates depending on which type of block is generated.

Comment: If nothing else, consider wrapping it up into a function `IsBlockCoordinate(i, j)` or something

Comment: `j==10` and `j==width` are two distinct possibilities? The reason I ask is because every other condition is `if { } else { }` and if for some reason `j == 10 == width` you will be printing two `|`.

Comment: width is equal to 40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Tas' thought, you could write a function to check those coordinates like this.

```
bool isBlockCoordinate(int i, int j)
{
    return ((j == BlockX[0] && i == BlockY[0]) ||
            (j == BlockX[1] && i == BlockY[1]) ||
            (j == BlockX[2] && i == BlockY[2]) ||
            (j == BlockX[3] && i == BlockY[3]));
}
```

And you could invoke it within your loop like this:

```
    if (j == width)
    {
        cout << "|";
    }
    else if (isBlockCoordinate(i, j))
    {
        cout << "0";                            
    }
    else
    {       
        cout << " ";
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I am a bit new with C++, could you elaborate a bit how I would work this into the loop? I get an error, expecting an ;.

Comment: I was stupid, I wrote the function inside the draw function. This solution works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @TheProgramMAN123 You're welcome, I'm glad to hear it's working for you.